# PHP Is it possible to send a unique value for each POST form in my while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

I currently have a database with different places as my rows, each place having an id, a name and a picture.

I'm trying to make a while loop that spits out a form for each place with a submit input and a div acting as its label. And I want each form to output each corresponding placeId. I tried doing it with `<input type='text' id='PlaceIdInput' name='PlaceIdInput' value='$PlaceId'>`, but figured out quickly that it only outputs the first PlaceId being 1, even if I clicked on place number 2 or 3.

I guess it's because they all have the same input name which is bad.

Sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology, I'm still in highschool with english being my second langauge. I really appreciate your support! :D

while($rad = $resultat->fetch_assoc()){

```
$PlaceId=$rad["PlaceId"];
$PlaceName=$rad["PlaceName"];
$PlacePicture=$rad["PlacePicture"];

echo("

    <form method='POST'>
        <input id='PlaceInput' type='submit' name='Place' value='Place'>

        <label for='PlaceInput'>
            <div class='PlaceDiv'>
                <p class='PlaceName'>$PlaceName</p>

                <div class='ImageDiv'>
                    <img class='Image' src='$PlacePicture'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </label>    

        <input type='text' id='PlaceIdInput' name='PlaceIdInput' value='$PlaceId'>
    </form>
");
```

}

if(isset($_POST["Place"])){

```
$PlaceIdInput = $_POST["PlaceIdInput"];

$sql = "UPDATE User SET UserCurrentPlace='$PlaceIdInput' WHERE UserId='$UserId'";
if($kobling->query($sql)){
} 
else {
    echo($kobling->error);
}
```

}

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Are you posting the form using javascript or something? There's no reason for the above to post the same `PlaceIdInput` if they are in different forms otherwise. However, if you're using javascript and are fetching the value using the ID, you will most likely only get the first input since they all have the same ID. ID's must be unique within the document.

Comment: No, I'm using php to post the form

Comment: Just tried your code and I'm getting different ID's. I do get the same `Place`though since that's hard coded.

Comment: *I guess it's because they all have the same input name which is bad.* - no, you need them all to be the same.  Only one of your many forms get submitted when a button is pressed.  The `<input>` ids being the same is an issue if you're using javascript - either you don't need ids or use class instead.

Comment: Oh weird. I tried clicking the submit button and it gave me the right value, but not when I clicked the label. I have no idea why it does that.

Comment: `<label for='someId'>` also uses the element ids, which you have duplicated, so that's why it clicks the first submit button when you click any label.

Comment: The `for` attribute on a label relates to a specific `id`. As mentioned, `id`'s _must_ be unique or the browser will use the first one it finds. So if you click on the label, it will always trigger the first submit button.

Comment: AHH I understand! Thank you! I fixed it by making the id='PlaceInput$PlaceId' and the label for='PlaceInput$PlaceId' instead. :D

Comment: @CaelumSuperus I was about to suggest that in an answer. Since you figured it out yourself, you should post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used the same id for multiple inputs. Therefore the labels chose the first input instead of their corrisponding ones. It was easily fixed by making the id='PlaceInput$PlaceId' and the label for='PlaceInput$PlaceId' instead.

Comment: If possible you can avoid all that and the use of ids entirely by placing the submit button inside the label (intrinsically making that label "for" that button) - however you have other form elements in that label so it's more complex.  Worth a look.